# How to make Promise resolve to trigger in the else statement javascript?

Tags: javascript, promise

[image]

As you can see it print only the `console.log("Testing")` and not proceed with the other logs in the `asyncCall`

```js
let i = 0;
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (i < 3) {
        console.log("Testing");
        resolveAfter2Seconds();
      } else {
        resolve("READY DONE!");
      }
      i++;
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log("calling");
  const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  // expected output: 'resolved'
  console.log("waiting for result");
  console.log(result);

  console.log("send array");
}

asyncCall();
```

Comment: You never resolve the *first* promise you make. You just recursively call the function and *eventually* resolve one of the further promises made but not the top level one.

Comment: any example thx. So may be to store the all the promises and resolve the all at once?

Comment: This will fix your problem: `resolveAfter2Seconds().then(resolve);`, because not all paths point to the resolution of the promise.

Comment: `if (i < 3) { console.log("Testing");  resolveAfter2Seconds().then(resolve); }`

Comment: Yes it do the trick. But i want to resolved only when it goes to the else  statement.

Comment: And you will. You'd only resolve the top-most promise (as well as the entire chain) when you *eventually* go into the `else` once. Until then, you're stacking pending promises and you'd resolve them all at once like a domino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps.

```js
let i = 0;
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const resolveFn = resolve;
    setTimeout(function tick(){
      if(i != 3){
        i++;
        console.log(i);
        setTimeout(tick, 1000);
      }else{
        resolveFn("READY DONE!");
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log("calling");
  const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  // expected output: 'resolved'
  console.log("waiting for result");
  console.log(result);

  console.log("send array");
}

asyncCall();
```

Thanks